# Does default XML namespace need a prefix?

Tags: .net, xml, powershell, namespaces

**Background**: I'd like to develop a PowerShell script to manipulate the contents of a *.regsvr file. This is an XML file used to export/import registered SQL servers with SQL Server Management Studio. Here's a [blog pos](http://sqlbg.wordpress.com/2010/11/02/sql-server-centralized-managementregistering-multiple-instances-at-once/)t that talks about using SQL queries to create the file. I want to do more than just create a file, I want to manipulate existing export files.

**Issue**: The problem I'm having is that I can't figure out how to read in the XmlDocument using the default name space.

Example with a namespace that I cannot get to work as expected:

```
$xmlstring = @'
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<model xmlns="http://schemas.serviceml.org/smlif/2007/02">
  <identity/>
</model>
'@

$doc = new-object System.Xml.XmlDocument
$doc.LoadXml($xmlstring)

$nsmgr = new-object System.Xml.XmlNamespaceManager($doc.NameTable)
$nsmgr.AddNamespace([String]::Empty, "http://schemas.serviceml.org/smlif/2007/02")
$nsmgr.PushScope()

$xpath = "/model"
$doc.SelectNodes($xpath, $nsmgr).count
```

The output is 0, but 1 was expected.

This works:

```
$xmlstring = @'
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<model xmlns="http://schemas.serviceml.org/smlif/2007/02">
  <identity />
</model>
'@

$doc = new-object System.Xml.XmlDocument
$doc.LoadXml($xmlstring)

$nsmgr = new-object System.Xml.XmlNamespaceManager($doc.NameTable)
$nsmgr.AddNamespace("x", "http://schemas.serviceml.org/smlif/2007/02")
$nsmgr.PushScope()

$xpath = "/x:model"
$doc.SelectNodes($xpath, $nsmgr).count
```

And gives me an output of 1. How I can specify the default namespace and avoid using a prefix in the xpath query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

XML namespaces don't have to exist even when specified in URL form.  They're primarily just unique names.  You have found the right way to access elements in the default namespace - you have to specify a prefix.  I use 'dns' as a prefix to represent the default namespace.

Comment: Or to put it another way: in XPath, no prefix always means no namespace. To access elements in a namespace you need a prefix. Even if, in the source document, it's the default namespace.